# PHP как написать такую рекурсию в функции?

Tags: php, функции

1. Рекурсивная функция, которая будет принимать 2 параметра: a и b - и возвращать число a в степени b.
   2 Проверить функцию.
   Примечание: Ключевой строкой будет что-то типа этого: return

```js
$a * func($a, $b – 1);
```

- то есть углубляться внутрь до тех пор, пока $b не станет равной 0. Когда это будет, возвращаем 1 и начинаем подниматься вверх вплоть до выхода.

Comment: ну дак вы можете написать функцию, определить там 2 аргумента `a` и `b`. В начале функции проверить равно ли b единицы или нет. и вызвать рекурсивно?

Answer (score 3):

Если вам нужно возведение в степень то функция уже есть: `pow` http://php.net/manual/ru/function.pow.php

Если-же просто хотите знать как рекурсию делать, то вот пример, возведения в степень:

```
function myRecursion($x, $n) {
  if ($n == 0) {
    return 1;
  }
  if ($n < 0) {
    return myRecursion(1/$x, -$n);
  }
  return $x * myRecursion($x, $n-1);
}

var_dump(myRecursion(5, -5));
```

Comment: Благодарю положительной оценкой. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
function func($a, $b)
{
    if($b !== 0) {
        return $a * func($a, $b - 1);
    } 

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: `-$b` это корень будет, и нужен ли вам тут `else` ?

Comment: @teran, else не нужен, вы правы, а корень с чего? Запись эквивалента ведь `$b - 1`. Спасибо, вы меня уже в третий раз поправляете. :)

Comment: `-$b` не эквивалента `$b-1`. `-$b` - это поменять знак :>

Comment: это как это эквивалентна? `-$b = $b - 1` что ли ? ааа, понял, вы видимо имели в виду `--$b` и забыли один минус

Comment: Совершено верно! Спасибо ещё раз, ребята!:))